# How to get returned value of function javascript

Tags: javascript, function, xmlhttprequest, return

I am trying to write my own Xhr wrapper as practice. I am in the process of getting things to work cross browser I came across this piece of code that initiates a xhr object for all browsers IE5.5+

But i personally dont really understand how to now use this instantiated xhr object.

See the code below:

```
(function () {
    try {
        return new(this.XMLHttpRequest || ActiveXObject)('MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0');
    } catch (e) {}
})();
```

Could someone explain to me how to use the instantiated xhr object?
And maybe for my own learning experience how this `(function (){})();` thing works

If something is unclear let me know so I can clarify!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your expression is an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) - you define a function and call it right away. Since you don't assign the result to anything, it's lost. So either do

```
var req = (function () {
    try {
        return new(this.XMLHttpRequest || ActiveXObject)('MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0');
    } catch (e) {}
})();
```

or (more readable)

```
function getRequest() {
    try {
        return new(this.XMLHttpRequest || ActiveXObject)('MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0');
    } catch (e) {}
}

var req = getRequest()
```

Not sure about all that `ActiveXObject` stuff though.